# ionic tabs badge don't working if set badge = "object"

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, badge

```
<ion-tab title="name" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.home" badge="12" badge-style="badge-assertive"><ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-tab>
```

this code is ok , badges can normal display, but if code is :

```
<ion-tab title="我的任务" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.home" badge="badgenum" badge-style="badge-assertive"><ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-tab>
```

and in controller:`$scope.badgenum = 12;`
that badges don't display,please help me ,thanks!

Comment: Which version of Angular and Ionic are you using?

Comment: @SumiStraessle angular 1.5.3  ionic 1.3.3  , what problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should do two way bind like  this.

```
 badge="{{badgenum}}"
```

the full code

```
  <ion-tab title="我的任务" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.home" badge="{{badgenum}}" badge-style="badge-assertive"><ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-tab>
```

Comment: badge = "{{badgenum}}"  is error, it will console:Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{badgenum}}] starting at [{badgenum}}].

Comment: Ideally it should work. I guess  you have a wrong code somewhere else.

Comment: what is your ionic or angular version

Comment: this points to a scoping problem. could you add your controller to the code snippet ?